# Samza: Delay processing of messages until timestamp

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, apache-samza

I'm processing messages from a Kafka topic with Samza. Some of the messages come with a timestamp in the future and I'd like to postpone the processing until after that timestamp. In the meantime, I'd like to keep processing other incoming messages.

What I tried to do is make my `Task` queue the messages and implement the `WindowableTask` to periodically check the messages if their timestamp allows to process them. The basic idea looks like this:

```
public class MyTask implements StreamTask, WindowableTask {

    private HashSet<MyMessage> waitingMessages = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public void process(IncomingMessageEnvelope incomingMessageEnvelope, MessageCollector messageCollector, TaskCoordinator taskCoordinator) {
        byte[] message = (byte[]) incomingMessageEnvelope.getMessage();
        MyMessage parsedMessage = MyMessage.parseFrom(message);

        if (parsedMessage.getValidFromDateTime().isBeforeNow()) {
            // Do the processing
        } else {
            waitingMessages.add(parsedMessage);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void window(MessageCollector messageCollector, TaskCoordinator taskCoordinator) {
        for (MyMessage message : waitingMessages) {
            if (message.getValidFromDateTime().isBeforeNow()) {
                // Do the processing and remove the message from the set
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously has some downsides. I'd be losing my waiting messages in memory when I redeploy my task. So I'd like to know the best practice for delaying the processing of messages with Samza. Do I need to reemit the messages to the same topic again and again until I can finally process them? We're talking about delaying the processing for a few minutes up to 1-2 hours here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use key-value store of Samza to keep state of your task instance instead of in-memory `Set`. 
It should look something like:

```
public class MyTask implements StreamTask, WindowableTask, InitableTask {

  private KeyValueStore<String, MyMessage> waitingMessages;


  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public void init(Config config, TaskContext context) throws Exception {
    this.waitingMessages = (KeyValueStore<String, MyMessage>) context.getStore("messages-store");
  }

  @Override
  public void process(IncomingMessageEnvelope incomingMessageEnvelope, MessageCollector messageCollector,
      TaskCoordinator taskCoordinator) {
    byte[] message = (byte[]) incomingMessageEnvelope.getMessage();
    MyMessage parsedMessage = MyMessage.parseFrom(message);

    if (parsedMessage.getValidFromDateTime().isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
      // Do the processing
    } else {
      waitingMessages.put(parsedMessage.getId(), parsedMessage);
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void window(MessageCollector messageCollector, TaskCoordinator taskCoordinator) {
    KeyValueIterator<String, MyMessage> all = waitingMessages.all();
    while(all.hasNext()) {
      MyMessage message = all.next().getValue();
      // Do the processing and remove the message from the set
    }
  }

}
```

If you redeploy you task Samza should recreate state of key-value store (Samza keeps values in special kafka topic related to key-value store). You need of course provide some extra configuration of your store (in above example for `messages-store`).

You could read about key-value store here (for the latest Samza version): 
https://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.14/container/state-management.html

Answer (score 2):

It's important to keep in mind, when dealing with message queues, is that they perform a very specific function in a system: they hold messages while the processor(s) are busy processing preceding messages. It is expected that a properly-functioning message queue will deliver messages on demand.  What this implies is that as soon as a message reaches the head of the queue, the next pull on the queue will yield the message.

Notice that delay is not a configurable part of the equation. Instead, delay is an *output variable* of a system with a queue. In fact, [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law) offers some interesting insights into this.

So, in a system where a delay is necessary (for example, to join/wait for a parallel operation to complete), you should be looking at other methods. Typically a queryable database would make sense in this particular instance. If you find yourself keeping messages in a queue for a pre-set period of time, you're actually using the message queue as a database - a function it was not designed to provide. Not only is this risky, but it also has a high likelihood of hurting the performance of your message broker.