# rabbitmq: should we use delayed messages with long delays from rabbitmq consumers

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

We want a rabbitmq message to be consumed by the queue after a certain delay that is in days for now but could in weeks or months in the future.

The exact scenario is:- we have a classified website where stock inserted by the user has to be deleted automatically after exactly 7 days. So, is it a good idea to publish rabbitmq message to delete the stock with a delay of 7 days. We want this to be deleted exactly after 7 days so nightly/hourly job to check stocks and delete them would not work.

I know its possible and read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444208/delayed-message-in-rabbitmq) but Is using [rabbitmq-scheduling](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/) correct for such scenarios? OR is there any other alternative to solve this?

Comment: I think that a major issue with using RabbitMQ for this application is that you need the stock deleted guaranteed while RabbitMQ provides a best try type of approach in which if no one is there to take a message then the message is discarded. That would not seem to be appropriate for a classified website where guaranteed action on a specific time is required.

Comment: but we will keep a consumer running to consume messages

Comment: It is possible, but it's bad design. Just like it is possible to build your house out of straw, you can force the message broker to do this. However, since the primary function of the broker is to connect producers with consumers, delays are not part of that purpose. I would recommend the use of a database.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295196/samza-delay-processing-of-messages-until-timestamp/48387262#48387262

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delayed message in RabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444208/delayed-message-in-rabbitmq)

Comment: Don't do this. Use a real scheduling framework to publish a "delete" message after 7 days have elapsed.